# Authentication issue when using ADAL to retrieve Visual Studio Online work items on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-devops, adal

I'm writing an ASP.NET web application that will have read/write access to our organization's VSO work items. In order to be able to track who made which changes, I'm looking to authenticate the currently logged in user using Windows Authentication. OAuth is unfortunately not an option, since it's been disabled in our org's VSO.

I currently have the following basic code in my controller:

```
var client = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://orgName.visualstudio.com/"));

WorkItemStore workItemStore = client.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
projectsList = workItemStore.Query(@"some query");
```

This is working perfectly fine when I run locally. Upon deploying to the server, it fails with a 401 Unauthorized error. I have both Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled. Impersonation seems to be working, since

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

all return my DOMAIN\username (when disabling ASP.NET Impersonation, the last two return NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM as expected).

What I find weird is that when I actually provide TfsTeamProjectCollection with Basic authentication parameters like this

```
var client = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://orgName.visualstudio.com/"), new NetworkCredential("DOMAIN\username", "password"));
```

it still fails (works in localhost, fails when deployed).

I've looked for quite a few solutions, but nothing seems to be working for me here. For reference, my Web.config has the following lines:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: What's the result if you use this code: new NetworkCredential("username","password","domain")?

Comment: Same issue: works on localhost, fails when deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTS does not support Windows Authentication. So you need to add code in your application to handle the authentication.

VSTS support the three authentication type below:

1. Basic Authentication: You need to enable Alternate authentication credential or use [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) and then use `NetworkCredential(basicAuthUsername, password)`.
2. Authentication with Microsoft Account, use `VssClientCredentials()` or `TfsClientCredentials()`.
3. Authentication with Azure Active Directory, use `AadCredential()`.

For detailed information, check this link: [Authenticating (Visual Studio Team Services)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples#authenticating-visual-studio-team-services).

Comment: Looks like there's not really a choice without hardcoding an access token or a username/password pair. Is there a way to prompt the user for their credentials? Or is that impossible because the prompt would just show on the server?

Comment: @FedericoParedes I'm afraid that the answer is no as far as I know. You could create a sign in dialog in your code to ask your users to enter username and password.